# 1 switch controlling too much

Tags: switch

I just moved into a house.
The switch in the garage turns power to the garage door and a outlet in the garage ceiling connected to a light. Switch off so does the garage door.
Last night, after moving all day the kids sat down to watch TV. I turned the switch off to turn off the light and by default the garage door. But it turned off the TV in side the living room, we tried the outlet on the 90degree wall and it was off too.

By my immediate account there is 1 switch that controls 3 outlets and the garage door.

How do I reduce the control of this switch?[image][image]

The switch has 3 black wires going to it. 
3 white wires with a cap on them. 
1 neutral connected and 2 others taped to the 1.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please? (Turn the power off at the breaker first, of course!)

Comment: Hard to tell. Are there two blacks connected to one terminal of the switch? If so, they should be your switched hots and BTW should be pigtailed with only one lead to the switch.

Comment: If you have two switched hots coming off the switch you need to determine what each one supplies. Also, are you sure the switch controls the entire outlet (top and bottom) or could it possibly be controlling only half of the outlet which is more typical.

Comment: HoneyDo, that's a good point, but I think it's worse than that.   Note that the red wire is capped off. I have a feeling somebody may have replaced the outlet and fought with wiring it correctly.  Then just said, "screw it", I'm getting rid of this red wire once and for all, making both outlets switched.   But your idea is still a good thing to check.  Given that there is a red wire there, it may be possible to resurrect the original config. We should also have a picture of the affected outlets and all wires in their boxes.

Comment: I’ll work on those photos tomorrow. Thank you for the suggestions on how to make this more clear to diagnose. Had a plumbing issue today too...I’ve had a nice welcome to homeownership lol